# MVC 5 Bundle With most recent {Version} only

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 on my current project, I've noticed that by default when I specify the {version} on my bundles, all file versions will be bundeled on the result, for example, I've on my hard drive 3 ["File-A.1.0.0.js", "File-A.1.0.1.js", "File-A.1.0.2.js"], all the files will be included to the minified result.

My question is very simple, is there any way to specify that only the most recent file version should be considered to the bundle? in this case I just want to minify the "File-A.1.0.2.js"?

Comment: Are you saying that using the `{version}` token ends up matching more than one item?

Comment: why do you have all these old files on your hard drive (would´t be better to version them in vcs)?

Comment: What you're wanting is the default behavior of the bundler. If you're getting all the files included, there's something else going on. Perhaps post your bundle config, and maybe someone can spot what might be causing this.